# Including Helper Functions in Separate JS File (Client-Side)

Tags: javascript

First off, I know this is probably pretty low-level for the most part, I'm sorry for not really trying anything before asking this.

What methods would you guys suggest for including helper functions in separate files?  I'm used to node.js's `module` interface for doing this, but I'm not 100% on how to achieve similar functionality client-side.

Small example of what I'd like to abstract into its own file:

```
var helpers = (function() {
  var _helpers = {};

  _helpers.buildDateFromDelta = function(delta) {
    date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - delta);
    date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

    return date;
  };

  return _helpers;
})();
```

Comment: You've kinda answered your own question unless I haven't understood. Just have two files and include the helper file before the one that's going to use it

Comment: So say I put the above function into its' own file, and in another file (`src`'ed before the helpers file) I can use the helpers variable?  I'm guessing they both sit in the top-level scope then?

Comment: Haha, ok that does work.  Alrighty, hilarious my code was already portable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I had my helper functions coded were already set up in such a way I could include them in a separate file easily.

## HTML

```
<script src="/javascript/helper.js" type="text/javascript">
<script src="/javascript/file-using-helpers.js" type="text/javascript">
```

## helper.js

```
var helpers = (function() {
  var _helpers = {};

  _helpers.buildDateFromDelta = function(delta) {
    date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - delta);
    date.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

    return date;
  };

  return _helpers;
})();
```

## file-using-helpers.js

```
var date = helpers.buildDateFromDelta(0);
console.log(date.getFullYear());  // Works

var otherIIFEExample = (function(lib) {
  console.log(lib.buildDateFromdelta(0).getFullYear());
})(helpers);
```

This works because when declaring the helper variable, it was set on the global scope (I'm assuming).  Other top-scoped files included after that file are able to use that variable as well.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but, this is what I would do (This is assuming you're running this on a HTML page)

```
var s = document.createElement("script");
s.src = "external.js";
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s);
```

This code goes in the main js file. 
Hope that helps!

Comment: ah I read your question as you only wanted to include one file in the source.